# Chart.js custom legend inside of chart

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

[fiddle of where I'm at so far](https://jsfiddle.net/8trc5470/)

I'm using chart.js, and I'm trying to create a legend that is inside the chart, and not a separate piece of html. I see a lot of posts about legendCallback, but that seems like it only works if you want the legend to be in an html block, and not a part of your canvas that chart.js renders on.

I need this to be all on the canvas, underneath the "Title" that I've place on the chart myself. The dates are my chart labels, the "Title" is a dataset where only the middle piece of data is set to visible, and the dashed line is my fifth dataset.

I'm preventing the title and dashed line datasets from showing up in the legend with this

```
legend: {
      labels: {
        filter: function(item, chart) {            
          return !item.text.includes('hide');
        }
      }
    }
```

Further, I'd like my legends to look more like their lines:
[image]
[image]

If it's not possible to make custom shapes like that, is there any way to fill the rectangles in the legends, without changing the fill of my data points?

Edit: Sorry for the wonky variable declaration at the top, it's because this script get's transformed into a scirban template.